# Magento 2 – How to off the autocomplete on forms on the admin

Tags: magento2, adminform, autocomplete

How to off the autocomplete on forms on the admin

[image]

Comment: it's off-topic , its related to your browser and not magento.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to Magento. This is browser specific.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow highlight means that you have, at some point, allowed your browser to save the username and password for this site.

So this is a browser feature, not a Magento one.

Consult the help for your browser to find out how to remove saved passwords.

If you want to disable autocomplete on input fields in a custom module, you can add the HTML attribute `autocomplete="off"` to certain form fields (see link below) to prevent browsers from automatically injecting any saved credential into such a field.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion for more information about using the `autocomplete` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser's saved password. It will solve this problem.