# How to remove autofill email id in email fields Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, login, newsletter

In my newsletter and login page, whenever I open the page it prefills the email. I don't know how Magento is doing this, I want to remove the autofill of email in Magento.

[image]

And I want to remove the prefilled email id from the newsletter part.
I don't know how Magento 2 is doing this from b backend.

Comment: This email from your browser...check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236497/magento-2-how-to-off-the-autocomplete-on-forms-on-the-admin#236500

Answer (score 0):

This is a your browser issue.

If you have a chrom browser then refer the following steps :

There’s an easy fix for this—you’ll just need to head over to Chrome’s settings. If you want to delete all autofill entries and saved text, follow these steps:

1) Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar (the icon featuring three vertical dots)

2) Select More Tools > Clear Browsing Data

3) In the dialogue that appears, check the “Autofill form data” checkbox, then select the amount of data you’d like to delete from the dropdown menu at the top of dialogue box. (Select “the beginning of time” to clear everything.)

4) Click the “Clear browsing data” button when finished

If you want to just delete specific autofill entries:

1) Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar and select Settings

2) Click “Show advanced settings” and find the “Passwords and forms” section

3) Select Manage Autofill settings.

4) In the dialog that appears, select the entry you’d like to delete from the list. Click 
the “x” that appears at the end of the row.

Comment: i will do in my local system, How to do it all users system, this site is live, And i cannot go and ask every user to do that

Answer (score 0):

try to add `autocomplete="off"` in the input fields

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete='off" may not work in chrome browser. You can try to set autocomplete is "false", "no-fill".

Also you can write below js on page load, if above doesn't work.

```
jQuery('#email_address').val('');
jQuery('#email').val('');
```

Just make sure to add condition for only create account page and set global for newsletter text fiedl only. so other fields are not affected.

Comment: autocomplete "false", "no-fill" didn't work, and  what with jQuery('#email_address').val('');
jQuery('#email').val('');, if i clear the email field it will again gets populated by chrome browser autofill. How to resolve this chrome issue of autofill

Comment: Well, every time you open your created account page. emails field should be blank and that needs to be resolved even by auto-filled or browser cache. So write a code of js that blanks auto-filled fields on document.ready jquery function

Comment: I followed many links, but could not find the solution that works for me in my js , one of the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off/38961567#38961567